# Wordpress кастомный шаблон

Tags: wordpress

Имеется раздел `Категория с ID=1` у этого раздела есть подразделы, в папке с темой создал файл `category-1.php` для кастомизации шаблона, как сделать так, чтобы кастомный шаблон так же применялся и для всех дочерних разделов?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете сделать category.php и там уже определять, по какому из ваших шаблонов будет обрабатываться категория.

```
$term = get_queried_object();
if ( 1 === $term->term_id || 1 === $term->parent_id ) {
    get_template_part( 'category-1' );
} else {
   ....
}
```